# How to create redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want build redirect

from 
/root/root2/query 
to
http://example.com/query

I created following code in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^sorevnovania\/filter\/(.+)$ http://xn----8sb3aobdifmb0d.xn--p1ai/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Where I have mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sorevnovania/filter/(.*)$ http://xn----8sb3aobdifmb0d.xn--p1ai/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Guess it must be like that.